# jQuery or JavaScript code for restarting a specific jQuery countdown timer plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I am basically using this particular jQuery plugin for countdown timer:
https://github.com/sygmaa/CircularCountDownJs

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sygmaa/3gq88aL2/

(both are almost same)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {

    // Run the countdown
    $('.timer').circularCountDown({
      delayToFadeIn: 500,
      reverseLoading: false,
      duration: {
        seconds: parseInt($('.delay').val())
      },
      beforeStart: function() {
        $('.launcher').hide();
      },
      end: function(countdown) {
        countdown.destroy();
        $('.launcher').show();
        //alert('terminé');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My question is, how can I make a separate new button, which will restart the countdown timer when it is clicked.

So suppose, the countdown starts from 20..19..18...so on till 1...
And at the moment it is at 9.

If I click my new button, it should make the timer start again from 20..19..18 so on.

How can I do this.

I have tried tweaking the code with all my ability, but in vain.
I dont know, somehow..some object is not destroyed and interferes in the restarting when I create a new object to restart.
I'm just fed up and really confused.

If anyone could please help..I would be really grateful.

Comment: *«i have tried tweaking the code with all my ability...»* Post that!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP seems to make a request for code... There is no specific question on its attemps to code by himself.

Comment: Heyyy...i have trie attempting it...having been on it for the entire ay!!!

Comment: so, i basically added these to the circular-countdown.js    $.fn.gettimesec = function () {
        console.log("get time sec");
    console.log(myobj.getFormattedTimeByCircle());
  return (myobj.getFormattedTimeByCircle()/500);
 };


$.fn.estroy = function () {
        console.log("estroying");
    myobj.destroy();
 };



$.fn.restart = function (options) {
        console.log("resettt timerr");
  myobj.element = $(this);
  myobj.data = jQuery.extend(true, defaultOptions, options);
    myobj.init();
 };

Comment: then from my main code called this..  $('.timer').restart({
              delayToFadeIn: 500,
     size: 60,
     fontColor: '#fff',
     colorCircle: 'white',
     background: '#2ECC71',
              reverseLoading: false,
              duration: {
                  seconds: 25
              },
              beforeStart: function() {
              },
              end: function(countdown) {
      
      
  //$('.timer').abc();
      
      
              }
          });

Comment: after calliing $('.timer').estroy(); which basically destroys the object

Comment: tried a lot of other things as well!! but after re-editing and all..at the moment i am stuck with this. and my solution works also...but it has some minor bugs!! if some one very skilled at jquery could please help..i would be really grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

This modification sort of works. I am not familiar with all the ins and outs of creating or destroying the circularCountDown, but this does successfully start a new timer when you click on the timer:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('button').click(function() {
            runTimer();
      });

      $('.timer').click(function(){
            runTimer();
      });
  });

function runTimer(){
  // Run the countdown
  $('.timer').circularCountDown({
    delayToFadeIn: 500,
    reverseLoading: false,
    duration: {
      seconds: parseInt($('.delay').val())
    },
    beforeStart: function() {
      $('.launcher').hide();
    },
    end: function(countdown) {
      countdown.destroy();
      $('.launcher').show();
      //alert('terminé');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: yes, it does. but that is not what i am looking for. this will basically just start a new one without removing the old one and the old one will create problems for me. i want to either destroy the old one..and then create a new one. or just somehow..reset this very same object to the initial values..so that it starts again. but not being able to do that.

Comment: I don't think the authors of circularCountDown made a way to destroy the object before it was done. If they did, perhaps you could post that. In any case, perhaps setting the count down object to a variable, if it allows that.

Comment: i did try that as well. i made a vairable called myobj in circular-countdown.js and made 2 functions in it. 1 for myobj.destroy() and another one for myobj.init() etc. but still it has some kind of a bug. :(